# Организация OAuth Яндекс

Tags: oauth

Пытаюсь разобраться с авторизацией через Яндекс на сайте, реализованным на Flask [В документации](https://yandex.ru/dev/id/doc/dg/oauth/reference/desktop-client.html) написано:

> device_id - Уникальный идентификатор устройства, для которого запрашивается токен. Чтобы обеспечить уникальность, достаточно один раз сгенерировать

и там же:

> У приложения не может быть больше 20 токенов

т.е. получается я генерирую случайную строку 6-50 символов и запоминаю ее?

Идем дальше:

> device_name = '<имя устройства >'

Откуда мне его взять?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не обязательные параметры и для простой авторизации на сайте они не нужны.